# Dependent variable with Poisson distribution in lavaan in R: how to deal with it?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am planning to create a SEM model with lavaan.

Most variables are normal, however, my dependent variable consists in a count of times and it has a Poisson distribution. Is there any Poisson distribution adjustment in lavaan?

Another option could be to dichotomize the dependent variable, but that would mean losing information. In case, is there a logistic regression adjustment in lavaan?